# Gradle subproject configuration not invoked with configureondemand=true

Tags: java, gradle

Here's an analogous project layout of my use case:

```
gradle
├── parent
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── child
│       ├── build.gradle
│       └── src
│           └── main
│               └── java
│                   └── Foo.java
└── settings.gradle
```

With the goal of configuring the 'configureJava' task of the gradle java plugin in the parent such that all children will use the same configuration. To keep things simple, I've removed configuration specific to my use case.

File contents are noted below.

gradle/settings.gradle:

```
include ':parent:child'
```

gradle/parent/build.gradle:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    configure([compileJava]) {
        logger.info("******* configuring compileJava! *******")
    }
}
```

gradle/parent/child/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

gradle/parent/child/src/main/java/Foo.java:

```
class Foo{}
```

Now, if I am to invoke:

```
gradle compileJava --info
```

Whether or not my log message is output, as an indicator the subproject configure task kicks  in, depends on a particular configuration property: `org.gradle.configureondemand`.

If `org.gradle.configureondemand` is set to true, no message. If false, lo and behold; I get my log message.

My next thought is this must be due to my version of gradle. Though the behavior between what I have installed (v1.11) and the latest and greatest (v2.0) are the same.

My question is, as far as configure on demand is concerned; is this expected by design? Or is this a bug? There are a handful of [possibly related tickets on the Gradle JIRA instance](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2775?jql=text%20~%20%22configure%20on%20demand%22) however I'm not familiar enough with the project to be certain if an existing item might already cover this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With configure-on-demand, only the current subproject's build script and the root project's build script will get evaluated, plus those of any depended-on projects. However, your `settings.gradle` sets up a three-level project hierarchy (root-parent-child), which means that `parent` won't get configured.

Comment: I see. I had assumed the 'subproject' section implied a 'depend-on' relationship. Would you say configuring specific sub-projects in the root project be the best way to go? Configure on demand gives a huge speed boost in day-to-day tasks, and I'm hoping to structure things to retain that facility

Comment: Either that, or use `apply from:` to include common logic in subproject scripts.